# Unable to generate .reg file from .ocx file using regcap

Tags: registry, activex

When I try to register .ocx file(SelfReg) using Regcap.exe, .reg file is not generated and log file does not contain proper information. Can anyone provide some help or suggest an alternate solution(other than regsvr32) to generate reg file for .ocx file

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\Deployment\regcap.exe" /o "location of reg file" "location of .ocx file"

Answer (score 1):

I was having all kinds of problems with regcap crashing and returning error 8002801c.

My fix for this was to set Compatibility Mode for regcap.exe to "Vista SP2". Try it and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

For me Compatibility Mode had no effect.

However running it on a `tlb` file instead of a `dll` worked.

Note that it has to be run as Admin.